# React navigator blank screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to use react navigator with react native but I get only a blank screen, no errors. What is wrong here ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class MainScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        title="Success"
      />
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Index: {
      screen: MainScreen
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Index',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
);

export default AppNavigator;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a height to your MainScreen.

Do something like :

```
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Button
      title="Success"
    />
  </View>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I forgot to register the main app component. I added `AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => AppNavigator);` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class MainScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator/> //this is for starting routing
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Index: {
      screen: MainScreen
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Index',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
);

export default MainScreen;
```

U can use this for destination [Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack)

```
 static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
  }
```